# iText7, Is there a way to control carriage return inside rectangle?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I'm using iText 7 with C# and I have to write a long line.

With `canvas.BeginText().ShowText("My text")` I can't find a way to make the text pass on a second line, `\n` is not recognized.

So I used rectangles and document renderer but I have the same problem, I can't control where I want my text to create a new line.

I use an existing PDF (a model) where I have to write some texts (as short as a single line) and some paragraphs (composed of several lines). Those elements are defined in an xml where I can have some carriage returns to delimit new lines in paragraphs. Is short, the document is composed dynamically and it's content and element's placement are defined inside an xml file.

Comment: Why are you using low-level methods if you want to add text that fits inside a rectangle? See [chapter 2](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2-working-rootelement) of the tutorial. Is there a reason why you want to do something in a difficult way that can be done in a much easier way?

Answer (score 1):

Adding content with low-level methods such as `BeginText()`, `ShowText()`, `EndText()` and so on, requires a sound knowledge of the PDF specification (ISO 32000). The fact that you are surprised at the fact that `\n` is ignored tells me that you aren't that well versed in PDF.

iText was written for people who don't want to deal with the low-level syntax of PDF. For instance: if you want to add text inside a rectangle with iText, you just have to create a `Canvas` object to which you pass a `Rectangle` object:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
PdfPage page = pdf.AddNewPage();
PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(36, 650, 100, 100);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdf, rectangle);
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(FontConstants.TIMES_ROMAN);
PdfFont bold = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(FontConstants.TIMES_BOLD);
Text title =
    new Text("The Strange Case of Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde").SetFont(bold);
Text author = new Text("Robert Louis Stevenson").SetFont(font);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph().Add(title).Add(" by ").Add(author);
canvas.Add(p);
pdf.Close();
```

This example can be found in [chapter 2](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-2-working-rootelement) of the online iText 7 tutorial.
[image: long sentence inside a rectangle]

The screenshot shows how a long sentence was added inside a `Rectangle`, and how that sentence got distributed over different lines (introducing new lines automatically). The concept of the `\n` character doesn't exist in PDF (check ISO 32000 when in doubt). If you want to introduce a newline, it's sufficient to put one part of the content in one `Paragraph` and the other part in another `Paragraph`.

Comment: @herve On topic now: the screen shot I added shows how a long sentence was added inside a rectangle, and how that sentence got distributed over different lines (introducing new lines automatically). The concept of the `\n` character doesn't exist in PDF (check ISO 32000 when in doubt). If you want to introduce a newline, it's sufficient to put one part of the content in one `Paragraph` and the other part in another `Paragraph`. Why doesn't this solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It partially solve the problem. In my case I use an existing PDF (a model) where I have to write some texts (as short as a single line) and some paragraphs (composed of several lines). Those elements are defined in an xml where I can have some carriage returns to delimit new lines in paragraphs. Is short, the document is composed dynamically and it's content and element's placement are defined inside an xml file.

Comment: That was not clear from your question. We recommended you to improve your question. This is your chance to do so. Please be aware that PDF is not a Word processing format. All content inside a PDF is added at absolute coordinates (fixed locations). You can't just add content and expect that the existing content will adapt itself to the new content. You might want to explain how using a static document (the existing PDF) isn't contradicting your claim that you are composing a document dynamically. More clarification is needed.